# Issue in getting data from API in React

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect

So i've basically got 2 components on my page.
First is the search component where the users need to type their username and second one where their stats get displayed

and here is my API request call in App.js

```
useEffect(()=>{

    const fetchStats = async ()=> {
      const result = await axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/csgo/standard/profile/steam/${username}`, 
      {
        headers: {
          'TRN-Api-Key' : '***************************',
        }
      }
    )
    
    if(username !== null){
      console.log(result.data)
      setStats(result.data)
    }
    
    }
    fetchStats()
  },[username])
```

and this is the search component

```
const Search = ({setInputText, setUsername, inputText, username}) => {

    const inputHandler = (e)=> {
        setInputText(e.target.value)
    }

    const searchHandler = (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        setUsername(inputText)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input value={inputText} onChange={inputHandler} type="text"/>
                <button onClick={searchHandler}>Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

What i'm having an issue with is when i click a button in the username component the value(username) from the form gets stored in the 'username' state in App.js. Now i'm using this code in the stats component.

```
const Stats = ({stats}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{stats.data.platformInfo.platformUserHandle}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Stats
```

Here `stats.data.platformInfo.platformUserHandle` doesn't exist when the app starts so it gives me a LOT of errors. How do i keep the app from crashing till the user has input something and data can be sent to the stats component?

Comment: Just check it exists before accessing it? e.g. `{stats?.data?.platformInfo?.platformUserHandle || ''}` (or pass a fetched/loaded/ready flag)

Comment: `(stats?.data?.platformInfo?.platformUserHandle)?<h1>{stats.data.platformInfo.platformUserHandle}</h1>:null`

Comment: Oh okay thanks a lot, one more issue. The API runs just as soon as i load the app as its in useEffect. How do i stop that from happening? Want it to load only when i've clicked the button.

Comment: then do your request in the searchHandler function instead of the useEffect @Parth

Comment: Also on my first button click. Nothing happens. On first click username doesn't set. Works on the 2nd button click and after that. How to fix?